# Select if exist XML Element using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have following xml . As addr is empty in this case but most time its has elements like street,city,state . How do I make sure it exist . Cause for now LINQ query throws an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
  <author>
    <time value="20120620153233"/>
    <assignedAuthor>
      <id/>
      <addr/>
      <telecom value="tel:+1-781-271-3000"/>
      <assignedPerson>
        <name>Auto Generated</name>
      </assignedPerson>
    </assignedAuthor>
  </author>



 tbAuthor autor =
                    (from c in cdafile.Root.Elements(ns + "author")
                    select new tbAuthor
                    {                           
                        streetAddressLine = (string)c.Element(ns + "assignedAuthor").Element(ns + "addr").Element(ns + "streetAddressLine").Value,
                        city = (string)c.Element(ns + "assignedAuthor").Element(ns + "addr").Element(ns + "city").Value,
                        state = (string)c.Element(ns + "assignedAuthor").Element(ns + "addr").Element(ns + "state").Value,
                        postalCode = (string)c.Element(ns + "assignedAuthor").Element(ns + "addr").Element(ns + "postalCode").Value,
                        country = "US"
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: what do you have in ns variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [these extensions](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/XElementExtensions.cs) that will give you a default value if any part in the path doesn't exist.  The last path part in the Get can be either an element or attribute.  It will also figure out the namespace for you.

```
tbAuthor author =
    (from c in cdafile.Root.Elements(ns + "author")
    select new tbAuthor
    {                           
        streetAddressLine = c.Get("assignedAuthor/addr/streetAddressLine", "default"),
        city = c.Get("assignedAuthor/addr/city", "default"),
        state = c.Get("assignedAuthor/addr/state", "default"),
        postalCode = c.Get("assignedAuthor/addr/postalCode", "default"),
        country = "US"
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you can use [the whole library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) and write it this way (presuming that there are no other address child elements that would give you different results from what is desired):

```
tbAuthor author =
    (from c in cdafile.Root.Elements(ns + "author")
    select new tbAuthor
    {                           
        streetAddressLine = c.XGetElement(".//streetAddressLine", "default"),
        city = c.XGetElement(".//city", "default"),
        state = c.XGetElement(".//state", "default"),
        postalCode = c.XGetElement(".//postalCode", "default"),
        country = "US"
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This worked but I have some other elements which has some HTML as content . Its stripping out HTML content and just returning text . What I can do ?

Comment: @user1649941 You should post that as a separate question.  Yet from my understanding HTML is not proper XML and therefore have to treat the whole file as HTML.

Comment: @user1649941 You could try the extension GetElement to get the parent element that has the HTML, it will find or create the element if it doesn't exist, therefore you don't have null references.  Then you can manipulate that element to get the HTML it contains, if it is possible.  Without seeing the node in question, I can give little advice and that is why you should post another question addressing your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

one approach would be to use inline if

```
    streetAddressLine = (string)c.Element(ns + "assignedAuthor").Element(ns + "addr") == null ? "" : c.Element(ns + "assignedAuthor").Element(ns + "addr").Element(ns + "streetAddressLine").Value
```

Comment: It still shows error , I think because there doesnt exist streetAddressLine element at all .

Comment: did you apply the inline if to all properties(city,state,postalCode)?